# self-sizing collection view cells using swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a collection view with cells that can autosize.  previously i had used sizeForItemAtIndexPath but could not get the cell height exactly right for a textView with attributedString.  I've decided to abandon that approach and use the auto-sizing feature.  I have found some information here but mostly with objective-C.  I am only familiar with Swift. Even so, I have picked through it and it is still not working.

What I have done so far is to include the following code in my viewDidLoad:

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(
        width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 100)
}
```

the cell width is showing correctly however all the cell heights are stuck at 100 regardless of the content.

Is there something else I need to do to allow the autosizing to kick in?  I'm pretty sure my storyboard constraints are set up correctly.

Comment: hi.  thanks for your comment.  in ios8 collectionView and TableViews use autosizing to size the cell correctly based on constraints and content.  i'm just not sure how to correctly implement this in a collectionView.  I have done it in a tableView.  There are several posts with this being done in a collectionView but the code is in objective-C.  I believe I may need to implement a method in the cell subclass but not sure how to do that.  That is my understanding anyway.  If I'm wrong I'll go back to sizeForItemAtIndexPath and try to work out the attributed string textView height

Comment: sorry, I should mention the cells are being resized dynamically

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the `estimatedItemSize`, you should also make sure that you are *not* providing an item size via a delegate or datasource method. The point of the self-sizing mechanism is that UIKit will use the estimated item size as its initial estimate, and then calculate the exact height based on the Auto Layout constraints you've configured on the cell's contentView. Also, you need a Base SDK of iOS 8 or later.

This repo [reproduces Apple's example](https://github.com/algal/SelfSizingCellsDemo) from the WWDC session where they introduced self-sizing cells.

Comment: hi.  this looks promising but flowLayout.itemSize = UIViewAutomaticDimension is not recognized.  Am I entering this correctly?  I only see AutoResizing but that is not a CGSize

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was thinking of table view, where there is a UITableViewAutomaticDimension. For UICollectionView, you just don't set the itemSize at all. This repo shows a working example: https://github.com/algal/SelfSizingCellsDemo

Comment: I downloaded the project and can't really see where I am going wrong in mine.  I tried several things but the height keeps appearing the same.  I think I will just go back to sizeForItemAtIndexPath.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround might be to size the collectionView cells height and width in proportion to the screen size:

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let deviceSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
        //let cellSize = sqrt(Double(deviceSize.width * deviceSize.height) / (Double(33)))

        let cellWidth = ((deviceSize.width / 2) - 10)
        let cellHeight = (deviceSize.height / 4)

        return CGSize(width: cellWidth , height: cellHeight)
    }
```